# Pyinstaller Builds seemingly successfully, running the executable does nothing

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have an application I'm trying to build an executable for written in python. For the records, my dependencies are reflected in the following import statements:

```
import asyncio
import os
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from winsdk.windows.media.control import (
    GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager as MediaManager,
)
import musicbrainzngs
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from psgtray import SystemTray
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
```

I am running the command:

```
python -m PyInstaller --onefile --paths=./venv/Lib/site-packages app.pyw
```

This seems to run successfully as I don't see any warnings or messages. However, when I run the application by clicking on the exe or by running ./app.exe, a process appears in the task manager, but no UI window or console appear as they should.

I've also looked at warn-app.txt and I see all of the following, but I have no idea if these are actually causing the problem, and if so, why there are so many missing modules:

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running your program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
            tracking down the missing module yourself. Thanks!

missing module named pyimod02_importers - imported by C:\Users\adamm\Development\mediascrobbler\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py (delayed), C:\Users\adamm\Development\mediascrobbler\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py (delayed)
missing module named jnius - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.platformdirs.android (delayed, optional)
missing module named platformdirs - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.platformdirs.__main__ (top-level)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (delayed, optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), subprocess (delayed, conditional, optional), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), webbrowser (delayed), http.server (delayed, optional), distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional), setuptools._distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional), setuptools._distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (delayed, optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), subprocess (delayed, conditional, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional), setuptools._distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named fcntl - imported by subprocess (optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named typing_extensions - imported by setuptools.config._validate_pyproject.formats (conditional), setuptools.command.build (conditional), urllib3.connection (conditional), urllib3.util.timeout (conditional), urllib3._base_connection (conditional), urllib3.util.request (conditional), urllib3._collections (conditional), urllib3.util.ssl_ (conditional), urllib3.util.ssltransport (conditional), urllib3.connectionpool (conditional), urllib3.response (conditional), urllib3.poolmanager (conditional), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.metadata (conditional, optional), setuptools._vendor.packaging.metadata (conditional, optional)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional), shutil (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level)
missing module named _manylinux - imported by setuptools._vendor.packaging._manylinux (delayed, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging._manylinux (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.importlib_resources' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.jaraco.text (optional)
missing module named 'typing.io' - imported by importlib.resources (top-level)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
missing module named pep517 - imported by importlib.metadata (delayed)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.more_itertools' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.jaraco.functools (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.platformdirs - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.jaraco' - imported by pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.jaraco.text (top-level)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary (delayed, optional)
missing module named win32con - imported by setuptools._distutils.msvccompiler (optional)
missing module named win32api - imported by setuptools._distutils.msvccompiler (optional)
missing module named 'distutils._log' - imported by setuptools._distutils.command.bdist_dumb (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.bdist_rpm (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.build_clib (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.build_ext (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.build_py (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.build_scripts (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.clean (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.config (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.install (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.install_scripts (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.register (top-level), setuptools._distutils.command.sdist (top-level)
missing module named termios - imported by getpass (optional), tty (top-level)
missing module named usercustomize - imported by site (delayed, optional)
missing module named sitecustomize - imported by site (delayed, optional)
missing module named readline - imported by site (delayed, optional), rlcompleter (optional)
missing module named 'docutils.nodes' - imported by setuptools._distutils.command.check (top-level)
missing module named 'docutils.frontend' - imported by setuptools._distutils.command.check (top-level)
missing module named 'docutils.parsers' - imported by setuptools._distutils.command.check (top-level)
missing module named docutils - imported by setuptools._distutils.command.check (top-level)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.jaraco' - imported by setuptools._reqs (top-level), setuptools._entry_points (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), setuptools._vendor.jaraco.text (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.importlib_resources - imported by setuptools.extern (conditional), setuptools._importlib (conditional), setuptools._vendor.jaraco.text (optional)
missing module named setuptools.extern.tomli - imported by setuptools.extern (delayed), setuptools.config.pyprojecttoml (delayed)
missing module named setuptools.extern.ordered_set - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.packaging - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools._normalization (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), setuptools.depends (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.importlib_metadata - imported by setuptools.extern (conditional), setuptools._importlib (conditional)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.more_itertools' - imported by setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.config.expand (delayed), setuptools.config.pyprojecttoml (delayed), setuptools._itertools (top-level), setuptools._entry_points (top-level), setuptools.msvc (top-level), setuptools._vendor.jaraco.functools (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.utils' - imported by setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.tags' - imported by setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.version' - imported by setuptools.config.setupcfg (top-level), setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named importlib_metadata - imported by setuptools._importlib (delayed, optional)
missing module named trove_classifiers - imported by setuptools.config._validate_pyproject.formats (optional)
missing module named packaging - imported by setuptools.config._validate_pyproject.formats (optional)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers' - imported by setuptools.config.setupcfg (top-level), setuptools.config._apply_pyprojecttoml (delayed)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements' - imported by setuptools.config.setupcfg (top-level), setuptools._reqs (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.markers' - imported by setuptools.config.setupcfg (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named simplejson - imported by requests.compat (conditional, optional)
missing module named dummy_threading - imported by requests.cookies (optional)
missing module named zstandard - imported by urllib3.response (optional), urllib3.util.request (optional)
missing module named brotli - imported by urllib3.response (optional), urllib3.util.request (optional)
missing module named brotlicffi - imported by urllib3.response (optional), urllib3.util.request (optional)
missing module named win_inet_pton - imported by socks (conditional, optional)
missing module named cryptography - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (top-level), requests (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'OpenSSL.crypto' - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'cryptography.x509' - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (delayed, optional)
missing module named OpenSSL - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (top-level)
missing module named chardet - imported by requests.compat (optional), requests (optional), requests.packages (optional)
missing module named urllib3_secure_extra - imported by urllib3 (optional)
missing module named olefile - imported by PIL.FpxImagePlugin (top-level), PIL.MicImagePlugin (top-level)
missing module named 'packaging.version' - imported by PIL.Image (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy - imported by PIL.Image (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named _dummy_thread - imported by cffi.lock (conditional, optional)
missing module named dummy_thread - imported by cffi.lock (conditional, optional)
missing module named thread - imported by cffi.lock (conditional, optional), cffi.cparser (conditional, optional)
missing module named cStringIO - imported by cPickle (top-level), cffi.ffiplatform (optional)
missing module named copy_reg - imported by cPickle (top-level), cStringIO (top-level)
missing module named cPickle - imported by pycparser.ply.yacc (delayed, optional)
missing module named cffi._pycparser - imported by cffi (optional), cffi.cparser (optional)
missing module named defusedxml - imported by PIL.Image (optional)
runtime module named six.moves - imported by pystray._base (top-level), pystray._win32 (top-level), pystray._xorg (top-level)
missing module named 'Xlib.XK' - imported by pystray._xorg (top-level)
missing module named 'Xlib.threaded' - imported by pystray._xorg (top-level)
missing module named Xlib - imported by pystray._xorg (top-level)
missing module named StringIO - imported by musicbrainzngs.compat (conditional), six (conditional)
missing module named 'gi.repository' - imported by pystray._appindicator (top-level), pystray._util.gtk (top-level), pystray._util.notify_dbus (top-level), pystray._gtk (top-level)
missing module named gi - imported by pystray._appindicator (top-level), pystray._util.gtk (top-level), pystray._util.notify_dbus (top-level), pystray._gtk (top-level)
missing module named PyObjCTools - imported by pystray._darwin (top-level)
missing module named objc - imported by pystray._darwin (top-level)
missing module named Foundation - imported by pystray._darwin (top-level)
missing module named AppKit - imported by pystray._darwin (top-level)
missing module named urlparse - imported by musicbrainzngs.compat (conditional)
missing module named httplib - imported by musicbrainzngs.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib2 - imported by musicbrainzngs.compat (conditional)
missing module named 'winsdk.windows.ui.composition' - imported by winsdk.windows.ui.core (optional), winsdk.windows.ui.windowmanagement (optional)
missing module named 'IPython.core' - imported by dotenv.ipython (top-level)
missing module named IPython - imported by dotenv.ipython (top-level)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application is a system tray application with pysimplegui, and it seems that without the --icon flag with the asset for the application icon is required for it to run, it just hangs.